# How to delete non-contiguous areas of a sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to delete several area of a sheet which are non-contiguous, I used the union method to select them, and they do get selected on the sheet, but I get a message: Delete method of Range class failed.

```
Range("A4").Select
lrow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
lCol = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column



Union(Range("A4:D" & lrow), Range("H4:J" & lrow), Range("N4:N" & lrow), Range("P4:T" & lrow)).Select
'Range("H4:H500,I4:I500,J4:J500,N4:N500,").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlLeft
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?
thank you

Comment: Hi Thanks, I am trying to delete them, and then move everything to the left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Shift:=xlToLeft` instead of `Shift:=xlLeft`.  When in doubt record a macro and review the code for hints to the issue.

```
With Range("A4:P4", Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("H"), .Columns("N"), .Columns("P")).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End With
```

Comment: Thank you TinMan, that worked great. Your comment about recording a macro is right on the money, in fact I woke up this morning and was going to do that, don't know why I didn't remember it yesterday ( old age I guess) but I checked the answers here first and there was your solution and great suggestion. Thank you!